# MVC no entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UrunEkle(Urunler urun)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        string sql = "sp_UrunEkle";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UrunAd", urun.UrunAd);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UrunAckl", urun.UrunAckl);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UrunFiyat", urun.UrunFiyat);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_UrunEkle";

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        conn.Close();
    }

    return View();  
}
```

//Below codes index.cshtml..But I have UrunAdd page dont find source error.What can I do..I want to do MVC but no entity only with stored procedure..How can I do like that..Like this I looking for examples..Help me please.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UrunEkle", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UrunAd)
                </td>
                <td>
                   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UrunAckl)
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UrunFiyat)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Ekle" />
    </p>
}
```

Comment: What **exactly** does the error say?

Comment: Resource not found. and HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) have been removed, had its name changed, or may be temporarily unavailable. Please be sure to review the following URL and typed correctly.

Comment: Yes HomeController.cs and I have two Views..a index.cshtml and urunadd.cshtml..

Comment: You're using DisplayFor(), which isn't going to post any values back. It might not be matching the profile of your HttpPost method because of this...What Can I do.Paul...